# Split array string in javascript into multiple variables

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to split an array I get through jQuery.
Basically the output is : "variable", "variable2".

I want to split the output into different variables

I have tried the .split(',') and it does not work, it says: convert.split(','); is undefined...

I am using the parse javascript sdk

Comment: `.split()` is for *strings*, and it returns an array.

Comment: please add enough of your code to the question so that we can run it and see the problem for ourselves

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. I am not sure what is the point of splitting an array into variables. Do you mean that an array like : `["var1", "var2"]` should create the variables `var var1, var2;`. 
Which value should they have then ? What are you going to do with those variables ? 
I think it's a bad idea but I might be wrong